# Funny thing happened on my way through the review queue

Tags: bug, review, flags, vote-to-close

I was reviewing first posts earlier today and something strange happened when I flagged a question NARQ: immediately after submitting the flag, this is what I saw:

[image]

I didn't vote to close - I don't even have enough rep to do that. It's clearly a bug. Just thought you guys might like to know.

**Update**

Something similar just happened but I was too quick clicking 'Next' to grab a screen shot. Like last time, it was after flagging NARQ. I'll try to remember to double-check next time I use the specific flag. So far it only happens when reviewing.

Comment: [The post in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649721/server-side-validation-for-unique-fields) was in fact closed a bit over an hour ago (18:02:30Z, to be specific). It's possible that the question was at four close votes when it showed up in your review queue, and someone cast the fifth vote between that time and the time you submitted your flag, in which case the message would not be a bug.

Comment: @PopularDemand also check the 'we'll take a look at it' message. And my flag history tells me that I cast the flag at 17:22:47. So sue me, I ate lunch before posting on Meta.

Comment: Ah, never mind then.